# Suppose the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$, and that $|a| < 1$. Prove that $\{a_n^n\}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I started by saying that since $|a| < 1$, then $-1 < a < 1$, and since $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$, then $|a_n - a| < e$ for $e > 0$. Can we then say that since $a$ is contained in the interval $(-1, 1)$, then $\{a_n\}$ is contained in the same interval? Or is that only for closed intervals?

Comment: Then if that is true we can say that {a_n} is bounded and converges so then it is monotone, and since {a_n} is monotone, then {(a_n)^n} is also monotone?

Comment: $a_n$ converges to $|a| < 1$ means that there exist an $N$ s.t. if $n > N$ then $|a_n| \leq r$ for some $r<1$. This implies $|a_n|^n \leq r^n$ so... The main point here is that you need to show that $a_n$ is contained in an interval $[-r,r]$ for some $r<1$ for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** it suffices to note that there exists an $r \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
|a_{n}|^n \leq r^n
$$
(when $n$ is "sufficiently large").